# so how do you use mysqli $driver->report_mode?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying my newbie best to put together a production quality website.  So I regularly use

```
   $driver = new mysqli_driver();
   $driver->report_mode =  MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL;
```

That may, or may not, be the thing to do.  It helps me find things that just aren't quite 100%.  But there seems to be this index thing that I can not rid myself of.  The errors, even thou I use a try/catch poop on the net and wreck my header.  The site then dies with messages no user would understand.. I don't understand.

My question is this.  Among you that really maintain production sites, what do you do with the mysql driver?  Do you set it to MYSQLI_REPORT_OFF, which seems to work just find ... or what?

I'm not trying to be insulting here (god knows I'm not lord of php/mysqli) but I'd really like to know what you pros do.

Thanks. (and if this gets cut for superfluous... I tried grace)

Comment: Not an answer: many of those who maintain production sites don't use mysqli. It's 2016 now and 2017 is coming, PDO is used everywhere. And many people use actual frameworks like Zend, Symfony or Laravel...

Comment: What do the pros do? Like @Arcesilas says, it's avoid doing low-level SQL with things like `mysqli`. I'd highly encourage you to look at using an ORM like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) or [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) as a baseline. Even better, evaluate [development frameworks](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) for their fit with your coding style and needs. [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) in particular is very well documented and beginner friendly, there's tons of examples.

Comment: The problem you're having is you need error reporting, but you don't have a system for handling them. PHP doesn't provide one out of the box. Frameworks do. You can either write your own framework, which is extremely messy, error-prone, time consuming, and liable to leave you with this horrible monstrosity, or use one that already exists. Up to you!

Comment: The only "framework" I've used, if that is what it's called, is Bootstrap.  I use it pretty much exclusively for styling and built in widgets.  I'll take a look at Laravel.  "documented and beginner friendly" is what I want to hear.  Thanks again.

Comment: @tadman in fact, PHP provides a first class error handling out of the box. in 99% cases it's more than enough.

Comment: @YourCommonSense It provides *exception* handling, but in the context of a web application trapping things correctly and doing things like unwinding transactions or releasing resources is not always so easily done. I'd also hesitate to call it "first-class". As anything in PHP that statement is loaded with caveats.

Comment: @tadman an aborted script will release all resources and rollback all transaction.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Sometimes that's desirable, other times you want to do a partial rollback and things get crazy. Most frameworks provide an ORM with better encapsulation to make this a lot more sane. At the very least you'll want to display some kind of coherent page rather than barf out with an exception and a confusing error.

Comment: @tadman  It seems I misread your comment. It seems it is not on this particular problem but just a by-the-way suggestion. Got you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to create a great "Final Product" website that works perfectly and that, in the end, is the focus of all us developers with the sites we work on.

As you can see, the documentation for mysqli->report_mode method reads:

> A function helpful in improving queries during code *development and testing*.

While your intentions are well meant, this function is not for production purposes because, as you very well point out, it writes text that causes headers to not be handled properly.

While on the end product, you don't even need to call it at all, what you have to do is to evaluate the return value of every method called on your project.

For example, if you want to run a query and check for errors, you would do:

```
if (!$mysqli->query("QUERY CODE")) {
  // error handling code here
}
```

Or

```
// just for explanation purposes, this syntax is highly discouraged
if ($mysqli->query("QUERY CODE") === false)
  // error handling code here
}
```

On a production website (ideally) there should be no instances in which a query should not be completed successfully, but you should always evaluate to at least log the error on a file for future bug fixing and to alert the user in an elegant manner that there was an error that will be handled by the web master as opposed of showing them a white block above the layout of your site displaying code and paths that the user not only not understands, but that he/she doesn't care about, but that an evil user might take advantage of.

Also in a finished product, turn off all errors on screen and have them logged in files, not only queries but any other error that might arise.

While in the development stage anything goes, just make sure your site runs smoothly even with all errors turned on before turning them off and shipping it out.

I hope it helps.

Comment: `$x === false` is absurd. Just do `!$x`

Comment: Absurd or not it is completely valid, and seeing as he's a learning developer he might come across code like that from other developers (I know I have) and it's important he sees it means the same. We're all learning here, so no solution is absurd ... unnecessary, maybe, or over explanatory yes, but not absurd!

Comment: It's an anti-pattern that I see in a lot of code and leads to [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) where you have programs littered with these useless and bizarre rituals. It's much better to explain what `!` does if it's not clear than to test versus literal false.

Comment: And again you prove my point, we sadly come across such lame code, but yes, I should've clarified that `!` is the way to go and that the second statement was just an explanation. I'll edit that in the response.

Comment: This answer is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @tadman honestly, it's nitpicking. This answer has worse issues. It doesn't answer the question, for starter.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't understand the purpose of the driver - development.  Changes my whole outlook.  I'll think about PDO but I don't think using it solves anything here.  I don't see a compelling reason for me to switch over right now.  Thanks again all.

Answer (score 5):

> But there seems to be this index thing that I can not rid myself of.

Make it just

```
$driver->report_mode =  MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT;
```

However, it's better to fix the error before going in production. If you don't understand it, you may always ask on SO doe the explanation.

> Among you that really maintain production sites, what do you do with the mysql driver?

NOTHING.

> The site then dies with messages no user would understand.. I don't understand.

DON'T make it die with a message no one understands. It's your code makes it die. Change the code to a more friendly error message.

Comment: This could have been an excellent answer to a very good question. But heck nobody cares.